# playing audio in background and recording that background audio with video on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, avaudiorecorder

In my app i want to play background audio and video recording both audio and video will be record....

How can i do this functionality???

// Setup cam

```
-(void)setupDivAvCam

{

    self.capturingWindow.delegate = self;
    [self.capturingWindow setupWithOptions:@{DIYAVSettingCameraPosition : [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack] }];
    [self.capturingWindow setCamMode:DIYAVModeVideo];
}



#pragma mark - Rec video methods Start 


-(IBAction)captureVideo:(id)sender

{

    [self startCapturingVideo];

}


-(IBAction)stopVideo:(id)sender

{

    [self stopCapturingVideo];

}

//To start video recording

-(void)startCapturingVideo

{

    {

        {

      if(![[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"])
            {
                //To disable the camera button for some time untill image loads
                _cameraButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                [self.capturingWindow captureVideoStart];

            }
        }
    }
}

//To stop video recording

-(void)stopCapturingVideo

{

         [self.capturingWindow captureVideoStop];

}
```

**The  above code is to get the video**

I looked in several forums and they all couldn't deliver a satisfying answer.

My wish is to be able to play and record video while playing music at the background. I managed to do that with the help of a snippet I found. here is the code:

Comment: Do you want to play background audio and record at the same time or you want to record both audio and video. your question is not clear